# Debugging Chromecast app displays error message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have a custom Chromecast receiver that isn't working and I'm trying to figure out why.  When I cast to it from Chrome on my desktop my app starts up on the Chromecast but the Chromecast dialog just says `Connecting...`

[image]

And although my app does start up on my TV correctly, it seems like the sender eventually times out and kills it.  I receive the following error message:

```
chrome.cast.Error {code: "session_error", description: null, details: null}
```

So I decided I'd try to debug it by going to `http://192.168.x.x:9222`.  That page loads up fine, but when I click the `Remote Debugging (AppEngine)` link, I get sent to a blank white page at `https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_rev/........`.  In the Chrome dev tools I can see the following errors:

```
shell.js:3123 Uncaught TypeError: document.registerElement is not a function
    at Object.UI.registerCustomElement (shell.js:3123)
    at shell.js:3135
    at shell.js:3137
UI.registerCustomElement @ shell.js:3123
(anonymous) @ shell.js:3135
(anonymous) @ shell.js:3137
devtools_app.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: SDK is not defined
    at devtools_app.js:2
(anonymous) @ devtools_app.js:2
inspector.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: SDK is not defined
    at inspector.js:2
```

I'm using a 1st Gen Chromecast with firmware version `1.36.159268​`.

The error seems to be the same as described here: [Unable to Open Chrome Inspector & Debug Chromecast Custom Receiver](https://support.google.com/chromecast/thread/31627366?hl=en)

Comment: Got the same issue on 1st gen Chromecast. Everything seems to be working fine on all other Chromecasts. It's probably worth reporting at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205 .

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same issue the last few days, tried Chrome 86.0.4240.183 and Chrome Canary 88.0.4317.0. Identical console log errors, both on Chromecast gen 1 and 2.

Solution: Switch to Microsoft Edge, inspecting from **edge://inspect/#devices** worked straight away on both my Chromecasts. Available on Windows and Mac: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an old version of Chromium -- can't find old versions of Chrome.

https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium
(under "Downloading old builds of Chrome / Chromium")

Here's an example of one (~version 77 for macOS):
https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Mac%2F668249%2Fchrome-mac.zip?generation=1560304902825342&alt=media